# OuterHeight() function giving different values in each browser

Tags: jquery, css

While working with the `outerHeight()` function in `jquery 1.11.1`, I've noticed that the table I'm trying to resize doesn't have a consistent behavior across all browsers. In `FF` and `IE11` I can see that the cell height is not the same across all rows.

When writing all the values to the console to see where the problem is, in FF and IE I'm getting different values than what I'm seeing in Chrome. For clarification, I'm not using `outerHeigh(true)` and even if I did, I would still expect the same values in pixels.

Is there anything I need to be aware of when using this function?